# Excel : Drag cell with one cell gap

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the formula written in the cell B1 and need to drag it down till the `B100`.

**Example**:

Formula for cell B1

```
=(A2 - A1)
```

**Note**: Now I need to drag cell `B1` to `B100` and need one cell blank in between like shown below:

Expected Result:

```
A       B
-----------
2       3
5
8       1    
9
```

Is that possible to format the drag option?

Comment: @Jeeped, I apologize!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)<>0,A2-A1,"")
```

As pointed out by @Jeeped, above formula can also be written as:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2),A2-A1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if the `<>0` is really necessary. False equates to zero and anything that is not false is true.

Comment: @Jeeped - You are correct, formula will work without `<>0`. Thanks for pointing that out, answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

A typical VBA solution might be easily done with a [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx).

```
Sub werqtr()
    Dim i As Long, bs As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   'KNOW WHAT WORKSHEET YOU ARE ON!!!!!!
        Set bs = .Range("B1")
        For i = 3 To 100 Step 2
            Set bs = Union(bs, .Cells(i, "B"))
        Next i
        bs.Formula = "=A2-A1"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a doubt. Pl clarify if VBA solution is  possible or offered should question Tag be edited to include excel-vba tag? I have earlier edited OP Post.

Comment: @skkakkar - The question was originally tagged with [vba] and [excel-vba]. The tags were removed after I questioned *'why vba if want to drag down'* but I had already prepared by solution. I believe it can stand as an addendum to the accepted solution posted by [Mrig](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6075259/mrig).